# Is there a way to use a parameterized filter on a DataView?

Tags: asp.net, dataview

Is there a way to use a parameterized filter on a DataView?

I want to filter rows in a DataView based on a users' search criteria.  When doing SQL lookups I can use parameters which help resolve issues with both strange characters and protects against SQL injection.  While weird things from a user won’t return or harm data with my view, it will prevent a search from executing property.

If I have DataView DV, how do I set the row filter so that input “**test’test**” doesn’t escape the search string `dv.rowfilter= “col like ‘” & searchtext & “’”`?

**[EDIT]**

Since this just isn't possible I decided to use Linq with a regular expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to use parameters with a `DataView`. You can do a simple string replace to escape single quotes.

```
dv.rowfilter= “col like ‘%” & searchtext.Replace("'", "''") & “%’”
```

or use `String.Format` which, personally, i think is a little cleaner.

```
dv.rowfilter= String.Format(“col like ‘%{0}%’”, searchtext.Replace("'", "''"));
```